# Calling a coroutine on Dispatchers.IO (for saving Api results) inside a coroutine running (for Api call) on Dispatchers.IO to simulate a threadpool

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, coroutinescope

I have a usecase where I want to save to a database after making an API call.  I want to do all of this in a single operator/invokee function.

One option is to create a custom coroutine context and then use that as a threadpool.  I know Dispathers.IO is already a threadpool.  Can I launch the coroutine for the database inside the invoke function after the API call is complete?

Would be something like

```
suspend operator fun invoke(): Resource<List<JobPW>> {
        try {
            val response = jobsRetroInterface.getJobsList(
                

           
       CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
                jobsList?.forEach {
                    try {
                        //ToDo make sure that the owners have been set first in code
                        saveJobPWToDatabase.invoke(it)
                    } catch (ex: Exception) {
                        Log.e(TAG, "exception saving job to database ${it.job?.job_id}", ex)
                    }
                }
            }
```

I don't want the coroutine to wait for the thread to save the items to the database.  I would like to save the items to the database on a different thread, so the invoke function can return with the data from the API immediately.

I found what I thought could be another approach; but it's not working.  I tried to create a coroutineContext from an executor threadpool like this.

```
  val threadPoolContext = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(3).asCoroutineDispatcher()
```

I'm trying this

```
CoroutineScope(NetworkUtils.threadPoolContext).launch {
                jobsList?.forEach {
                        try {
                            //ToDo make sure that the owners have been set first in code
                            saveJobPWToDatabase.invoke(it)
                        } catch (ex: Exception) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "exception saving job to database ${it.job?.job_id}", ex)
                        }
                    }
            }
            return  convertResponseToJobsResource(jobsList)
```

Here is the whole invoke function for your reference.

```
    suspend operator fun invoke(): Resource<List<JobPW>> {
        try {
            val response = jobsRetroInterface.getJobsList(
                TokenUtils.getFirebaseUid(PosterPalApplication.appContext)!!,
                TokenUtils.getFirebaseAuthToken(PosterPalApplication.appContext)!!)

            if (response == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "jobs response is response is null")
                return Resource.Error("Failed to connect to server")
            }

            val jobsList = response?.entrySet()?.map {
                val id = it.key
                val jobJson = it?.value?.asJsonObject
                return@map NetworkUtils.gson.fromJson(jobJson, JobPW::class.java).apply {
                    this.job?.job_id = id!!
                }!!
            }

            runBlocking {
//
                launch(NetworkUtils.threadPoolContext) {
                    jobsList?.forEach {
                        try {
                            //ToDo make sure that the owners have been set first in code
                            saveJobPWToDatabase.invoke(it)
                        } catch (ex: Exception) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "exception saving job to database ${it.job?.job_id}", ex)
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
            return  convertResponseToJobsResource(jobsList)
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            Log.e(MainViewModel.TAG, "failed to get from remoted database, maybe no internet  ${ex.message}")
            return Resource.Error("No internet connection")
        } catch (ex: HttpException) {
            Log.e(MainViewModel.TAG, "failed to get from remoted database, maybe bad response  ${ex.message}")
            return Resource.Error("No internet connection")
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.e(MainViewModel.TAG, "failed to get from remoted database, unknown issue ${ex.message}")
            return Resource.Error("Failed to connect to server")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your question mentions threadpools a number of times, but I'm not sure what about threadpools you specifically are seeking. I'm not really sure what you're asking about. It is very unsusual to start a coroutine using a `CoroutineScope` that you immediately leave for dead, and it is generally unnecessary to specify which Dispatcher to use to call a suspend function since suspend functions handle their dispatcher use internally if they are doing any blocking work.

Comment: Maybe you can show more of the surrounding code and be specific about what you are not sure about. What is the "invoke function"? Is it another suspend function, or is it a regular function? Does it need to wait for the database write to be complete?

Comment: `runBlocking` should never be used from inside a suspend function or coroutine. There’s no valid reason to do that. What are you trying to accomplish by using it?

Comment: i needed to add the runBlocking line in order to use the launch keyword; but fixed it.  Replacing in the post

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need separate `ThreadPool`, you need separate **CoroutineScope that is tied to lifetime of Database**. Creating new `CoroutineScope` as shown in your code for every call is bad practice, you're not closing them.
2. Inject that `CoroutineScope` like how you inject the `Database` object
3. Call `coroutineScope.launch{}`

**Another option**:

Having some `DatabaseHelper` which will contain `Database`, `CoroutineScope` etc.. Then your use-case will call `DatabaseHelper.saveAsync()`. Encapsulating like this is better than passing `Database's` `CoroutineScope` around *(someone might close/cancel CoroutineScope which is not desired)*. You can also fake/mock `DatabaseHelper` for testing.

DatabaseHelper

```kotlin
// Probably Singleton class
class DatabaseHelper{
    private val database: MyDatabaseOrORM
    private val scope: CoroutineScope

    init{
        database = ...
        scope = CoroutineScope(SupervisorJob()+Dispatchers.IO)
    }

    fun saveJobPWAsync(jobList:List<JobPW>){
        scope.launch{
            jobList.forEach{ job->
                // database.insert(job) ...
            }
        }
    }  

    // not necessary if DatabaseHelper is Singleton
    fun close(){
        // database.close()
        // scope.cancel()
    }  
}
```

Use-Case

```kotlin
suspend operator fun invoke(): Resource<List<JobPW>> {
        try {
            val response = jobsRetroInterface.getJobsList(
                TokenUtils.getFirebaseUid(PosterPalApplication.appContext)!!,
                TokenUtils.getFirebaseAuthToken(PosterPalApplication.appContext)!!)

            if (response == null) {
                Log.e(TAG, "jobs response is response is null")
                return Resource.Error("Failed to connect to server")
            }

            val jobsList = response?.entrySet()?.map {
                val id = it.key
                val jobJson = it?.value?.asJsonObject
                return@map NetworkUtils.gson.fromJson(jobJson, JobPW::class.java).apply {
                    this.job?.job_id = id!!
                }!!
            }

            databaseHelper.saveJobPWAsync(jobsList)

            return  convertResponseToJobsResource(jobsList)
        } catch (ex: IOException) {
            Log.e(MainViewModel.TAG, "failed to get from remoted database, maybe no internet  ${ex.message}")
            return Resource.Error("No internet connection")
        } catch (ex: HttpException) {
            Log.e(MainViewModel.TAG, "failed to get from remoted database, maybe bad response  ${ex.message}")
            return Resource.Error("No internet connection")
        } catch (ex: Exception) {
            Log.e(MainViewModel.TAG, "failed to get from remoted database, unknown issue ${ex.message}")
            return Resource.Error("Failed to connect to server")
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide a bit of sample code?  How is that different from what I am doing right now, and what are the benefits of your approach?